# Not able to download file using webclient, but I am able to download it manually from the website

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void download_nse()
{
        string source_location = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2015/DEC/fo23DEC2015bhav.csv.zip";
        Uri uu = new Uri(source_location);

        using (WebClient fileReader = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
                fileReader.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);
                fileReader.Headers["Accept"] = "/";
                fileReader.DownloadFile(uu, @"d:\nse\notworking.zip");
                fileReader.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        source_location = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2016/JAN/fo05JAN2016bhav.csv.zip";
        using (WebClient fileReader = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
                fileReader.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);
                fileReader.Headers["Accept"] = "/";
                fileReader.DownloadFile(source_location, @"d:\nse\working.zip");
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please make your question specific, state exactly what's going wrong, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i'm trying to download a file programmatically, i have tried downloading the files before 2016. which i am not able to download thru the above code. but the same code is working fine for 2016 onwards file. but i will be able to download both the files manually from the website. there are so many files which i need to download. so i need pro-grammatical download

Comment: How's that empty catch block working out for you?

Comment: the code is working fine but catch block returns an error 403 forbidden. for the first try catch block, but the second try catch is working fine and the file is getting downloaded sucessfully. i have traced the block and found out. i'm just checking whether the code is been working then i will structure it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't access that link from my browser, so I suspect your browser is passing some cookies or something so authenticate with that server, where mine isn't, and your code is certainly not doing this. Either way, your question still doesn't really contain enough information to help.

Comment: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm ..... this is the weblink where u can select the bhavcopy from the dropdown and select a date and try getdata u will get a link and download the file without any authentication. I am not bypassing anything as far as i am aware of... have u tired both 2015 and 2016 link???

Comment: could any one help on this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the url you gave and see that when you select the "Date(DD-MM-YYYY)" and "Select Report" drop-down options and click on "Get Data", there is a GET request send to `https://www.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch` with three parameter like this: "?h_filetype=fobhav&date=02-04-2018&section=FO". And this GET request returns:

```
<p class="archive_title">F&O - Bhavcopy for 02-04-2018 </p><br>
<br><table cellpadding=5>
<tr>
<td class=t0><a href=/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2018/APR/fo02APR2018bhav.csv.zip target=new>fo02APR2018bhav.csv.zip</a></td></tr>
<tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

which contains the link to download file. so when you send the POST request without the GET it fails.
You can send a GET request first and then send POST with the returned link like this:

```
        string source_location2 = "https://www.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch";
        Uri uu2 = new Uri(source_location2);

        using (WebClient fileReader = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
                fileReader.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);
                fileReader.Headers["Accept"] = "/";
                fileReader.QueryString.Add("h_filetype", "fobhav");
                fileReader.QueryString.Add("date", "02-04-2018");
                fileReader.QueryString.Add("section", "FO");
                var response = fileReader.DownloadString(uu2);
                //using Html Agility Pack to parse the response and get the download link. you need to add this package through nuget package manager to project for this code to work.
                var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDoc.LoadHtml(response);
                var fileLink = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table//tr//td//a").Attributes["href"].Value;
                //now sending the actual file request...
                var fileReader2 = new WebClient();
                fileReader2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);
                fileReader2.Headers["Accept"] = "/";
                fileReader2.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://www.nseindia.com" + fileLink), @"d:\notworking.zip");
                fileReader2.Dispose();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi ahmet urun thanks for put in your efforts.
but still i'm not able download the files before 2016, from 1-1-2016 onward there isn't any issue downloading using webclient. any date which is prior to 1-1-2016 not able to download. throws an error 403 forbidden

Comment: Have you tried to download those date intervals with setting date parameter to date you want like this: fileReader.QueryString.Add("date", "<date you want>");

Comment: yes i have tried as you have mentioned. but anything before 2016 i'm not able to download. Please try 01-04-2015, in this date the file is available but throws an 403 forbidden error